# Android studio custom icon state_focused not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**custom_email_icon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email_focused"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email"/>
</selector>
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailText"
    android:layout_width="301dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_email_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    android:hint="Email Address"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Icon color change not working when I clicked to text. Same problem with the password line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a focused state, you can add a selector for a pressed and selected state like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_window_focused="false" 
     android:state_enabled="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email" />
   <item android:state_window_focused="false" 
     android:state_enabled="false"
     android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email_focused" />
   <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_focused="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email_focused" />
   <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email_focused" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_email" />
</selector>
```

Comment: its not fixed [screenshot link](https://prnt.sc/K9FufhF-uUiI) , [screenshot link highlighted](https://prnt.sc/lO5I322KeaNj)

Comment: email and password logo do not changing

Comment: I have edited my answer can you try that

Comment: I tried now but not worked

Answer (score 0):

All problem is this code line, I just removed it and fixed; idk why automatically its cames when I add vector.

```
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
```